# Let $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$ with $|z|=1$. Show $z^n$ diverges without appealing to the exponential/trigonometric functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

**Theorem.** *Let $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ with $|z|=1$, then the limit of $z^n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ diverges.*

Can the theorem above be proven without appealing to the exponential or trigonometric functions?
The reason I'm interested is to include the result in a set of notes on sequences at a point where the necessary machinery to define exponential/trigonometric functions has not been developed.

Comment: This so-called theorem is very very false. Where did you find it?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right, I forgot to include the condition $|z|=1$. I edited the question.

Comment: *Hint:* Assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty} z^n = a $ exists. What does $ z^{n+1} $ converge to? What does that tell you about $z$ and $a$?

Comment: suppose limit exist: you can explicitly compute the Cesaro sum (use geometric series) which $\to 0$ but limit must have modulus of 1.  Conclude $0=1$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it converges, let $l$ be its limit. Since you always have $|z^n|=1$, $|l|=1$ too. On the other hand,\begin{align}l&=\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}z^{n+1}\\&=z\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n\\&=z\times l.\end{align}But$$l=z\times l\iff z=1,$$since $l\ne0$.